# Property Sobolev space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be open, $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1\leq p<\infty$. Furthermore we take a function $f$ contained in the Sobolev space, $f \in W^{k,p}(U)$. Take a look at the following assertion:

$g \in C_b^k (U)$ $\Rightarrow$ $gf \in W^{k,p}(U)$.

Anyone with a counterexample or is it really true? I am not sure...

Comment: Does $C_b^k (U)$ represent the set of bounded with derivatives (up to order $k$) bounded functions on $U$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is right! Sorry for being not exact enough

Comment: This is true; proceed by induction on $k$ and use the product rule.